# Base on python-docx, create table after the specific text python

Tags: python, docx

I see the document of python-docx for handle word file in python. For the tutorial, I can use the `add_table` to create the table in the last line.

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
document = Document()
table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)
```

I want to create the table when I detect the specific word **create the table after line**. How do I modified my code?

```
    document = Document('./my_document.docx')
    start = "create the table after line"
    for p in document.paragraphs:
        if(start in p.text):
            ##  Create the table in here
            p.add_table(nrows=2, cols=3)
```